# how do i prevent outlook to keep re sending this email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
A message that you sent has not yet been delivered to one or more of its
recipients after more than 48 hours on the queue on dist012.mail.hostpoint.internal.

The message identifier is:     1VYQ2b-000Dxy-C2
The subject of the message is: RE: FKMP: Photo request TY
The date of the message is:    Mon, 21 Oct 2013 20:19:50 -0400

The address to which the message has not yet been delivered is:

```
Delay reason: mailbox is full
```

No action is required on your part. Delivery attempts will continue for
some time, and this warning may be repeated at intervals if the message
remains undelivered. Eventually the mail delivery software will give up,
and when that happens, the message will be returned to you.

Comment: Outlook is sending the message more than once it's your mail server that's doing it...

Answer (score 1):

You don't (and can't) really do anything... as the end of the message said

```
Eventually the mail delivery software will give up....
```

If you have access on the Mail Server itself, then yes you can delete it from the Mail Server queue. The mail are already in the Mail Server and the mail server is trying to send.

Your Mail Client (outlook) is only informing you what the Mail Server is doing, and why the email is not yet delivered (delay).

This way if you get a call from the email recipient "Why didn't you send my stuff over email" you can tell them the reason (ie. their mailbox is full, and THEY need to clear up some space to be able to receive your mail).

Hope this helps.